# Adjust legend width when colour and linetype are scaled manually

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this data:

http://pastebin.com/pAQePpxr

And this code:

```
ggplot(data = trial, aes(x = as.factor(Year), y = DV,group = TMT, col = TMT,linetype=TMT))     +
theme_bw() +
geom_point(size = 3,position = pd) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=trial$DV-trial$Error, ymax=trial$DV+trial$Error),
    position = pd, 
    width = 0.1,
    linetype=1) +
geom_line(position = pd) +
ylab("DV") +
xlab("Year") +
theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=rel(1.1),vjust=0.2),
    axis.title.x=element_text(size=rel(1.1), vjust=0.2),
    axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1)),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1)), 
    text = element_text(size=13)) +
scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1") +
scale_colour_manual(name = "Tmt",
                  labels = c("C", "S"),
                  values = c("red","blue"))+scale_linetype_manual(name = "Tmt",
                  labels = c("C", "S"),
                  values = c("solid","dashed"))
```

I am creating the following graph:

[image]

I want to make the linetypes clear in my legend.  I'm not sure if my manual scaling of linetype hasn't worked, or whether it is because the width of the legend is too narrow.  I have tried adding:

```
+guides(linetype=guide_legend(keywidth=5))
```

to adjust the width, but it doesn't work.  Any one got any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change width of legend keys you should use the function `theme()` and argument `legend.key.width=`. You will also need package grid to set units.

```
library(grid)
+ theme(legend.key.width=unit(1,"cm"))
```

But in your particular case you need to make another change to your plot. As you are setting `linetype=1` in `geom_errorbar()` both lines in legend will appear as solid. So you need to add argument `show_guide=FALSE` to `geom_errorbar()`.

```
  + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=DV-Error, ymax=DV+Error),
                width = 0.1,linetype=1,
                   show_guide=FALSE)
```

Comment: Can I ask one more related question?  I want to adjust the breaks in the x and y axes (i.e. change the axis ticks).  The usual method of specifying breaks=c(etc) within scale_y_continuous doesn't seem to work - is this because I am scaling the colours and so on manually?  Is there a way to change the axis ticks?  Many thanks.

Comment: For for this  + scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.35)) works without problems.

Comment: Thank you - I must have had some other problem with my code!  Much appreciated :)